# Creating an iPhone contact in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am trying to create a contact in the internal address book. My code is as follows:

in the CreateNewAccountPage.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
....
@interface CreateNewAccountPage : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate,
UITextViewDelegate, MainMenuDelegate, ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate> {
....
}

- (IBAction)goToContactCreation;
...
@end
```

In the CreateNewAccountPage.m file:

```
#import "CreateNewAccountPage.h"

@implementation CreateNewAccountPage

-(void)showNewPersonViewController
{
ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:picker];
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];

[picker release];
[navigation release];
 }

 -(IBAction)goToContactCreation {
[self showNewPersonViewController];
 }

 - (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
 {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
 ...
 @end
```

The error that I am getting is:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABNewPersonViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-ABNewPersonViewController in CreateNewAccountPage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

If I comment out the lines:

```
ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
...
[picker release];
```

I no longer receive the error. I am just trying to get a contact to be created. It doesn't have to do with accessing the contact list. I just want a button to create the contact.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Add AddressBook.framework, AddressBookUI.framework frameworks to your project.